# Showing an intro of React Native app only once?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I already have a Model view in react native that can be accessed from a button in the settings, and I would like it to pop up the first time the app is used. In other words, I don't have any problems with the view itself, just the functionality.

I've considered user React-native-simple-store but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: What do you mean by app is used? Does it mean initial page load?

Comment: When you want your model to be pop up for the first time when app is used. How do you want us to help you here without single line of code? How do we know that your settings button triggering your model to be open. Please share your code when you write questions like this for better and quick response from the community.

Comment: Hi @Eric - Is this what you looking for? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-intro

Answer (score 3):

To pop-up the modal you will have to set its visible props:

```
<Modal visible={this.state.showModal} ...
```

If you save this value into AsyncStorage, or any database, like RealmDB or Sqlite, you can always read the value and then make modal show-up only once. Put it in componentDidMount :

```
const value = AsyncStorage.getItem('once');

if (value !== null) {
  value.then((ret) => {
    if (ret === null) {
      // this is the first time
      // show the modal
      // save the value

      AsyncStorage.setItem('once', 'yes');
      this.setState({
         showModal: true,
      });

    } else {
      // this is the second time
      // skip the modal

    }
  }).catch(err => alert(err.toString()));
}
```

In your modal:

```
<Modal visible={this.state.showModal} ...
```

In your constructor:

```
this.state = {showModal: false}
```